# How to use javascript to slowdown a div transiton?

Tags: javascript, html

**html**

```
 <li onClick="changeHeight();" >Project Info</li>

 <div id="content-about-project" style="width: 100%; border:1px solid gray;">
content
  </div>
```

**Js**

```
function changeHeight() {
document.getElementById('content-about-project').style.height = "600px"
}
```

**What code does so far..**

The user clicks the link (a) and the js function is called, when this happens the div's height extends 600px;

**My question**

How do i slow down div when its extending its height.
right now its blazing fast and im not really liking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`classList.toggle()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM0KXlt-DWAhWG7SYKHdFGBJ4QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_element_classlist.asp&usg=AOvVaw2nBFW9BgEExGgCpfP8J9FJ) function .Its better with direct css property change in dom .And use [`transition`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq56_Zt-DWAhXLTCYKHRXaBMcQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Fcss3_transitions.asp&usg=AOvVaw1fWStUuPx3Uac5KLdgv0cW) for slow down effect

```js
function changeHeight() {
document.getElementById('content-about-project').classList.toggle('expand')
}
```

```css
.normal{

transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
height:15px;
}
.expand{
height:600px;
}
```

```html
 <li onClick="changeHeight();" >Project Info</li>

 <div id="content-about-project"  class="normal" style="width: 100%; border:1px solid gray;">
content
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript function `setTimeout`.

```html
<li onClick="changeHeight();">
    Project Info
</li>

<div id="content-about-project" style="width: 100%; border:1px solid gray;">
    content
</div>

<script>

    newHeight=50;
    function changeHeight() {
        if (newHeight<600) {
            newHeight+=5;
            document.getElementById('content-about-project').style.height = newHeight+"px";
            setTimeout(changeHeight,5);
        }
    }
      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this with css.

Rather than giving the in-line style ,
Append a class with the values.

Use min-height instead of height.

And make transition with css